# Obligation to Tell People Online if Changing Time Zone Before Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, internet, marit-ayin, time-zone, social-media

If a person changes time zones while going on a vacation, do they have an obligation to alert others to this effect? By using social media and other types of online sites (like Mi Yodeya), not telling people in advance might create the impression that they are doing these things on Shabbat.

Is this a case of [mar'it ayin](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Marit_Ayin/Suspicious_actions): leading people to believe that this person is doing something wrong?

Is it a case of [lifnei 'iver](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Lifnei_Iver): causing people to think that using computers on Shabbat is okay?

And if it is a problem, what is the minimum effort that a person needs to go to in order to inform others? Does a person need to add something to their public profile, for example? Is it necessary for them to change their status on Facebook? Is this issue discussed in any contemporary literature?

Comment: +1very good I am convinced that yes, he needs to be naki from hashem and from Israel. need to learn for proofs

Comment: Against these concerns would be the potential security concern of announcing to the whole Internet "hey, I'm not home so my house is empty!".  Many people I know are careful not to mention travel publicly for that reason.  It seems like the best practical answer would be to say *when posting* that it's not Shabbat for you yet, so you only deal with it when it comes up, but I don't know what the literature says.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I agree in principle that one option may leave things vague, by just stating "It's not Shabbat, here" or if you're really concerned about security, "xx PM Local time". Inevitably, someone will wonder what's going on, and others may pick up on something unusual from your normal habit and figure it out. You can always explain things later to those that wonder. There is an opposing rule called "choshed biksheirim" - essentially, others should be offering benefit of doubt, and not suspect that you did something wrong.

Comment: Are you assuming that it is forbidden to use a computer in Shabbat? Adding a link to support this would strengthen the question.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually a thing that happened with Naftali Bennett. One time he traveled to the United States and was there for shabbat and on friday afternoon US time he posted on Facebook and got blasted by people in Israel for posting on Facebook when it was shabbat israel time since people thought he was posting on Shabbat as they assumed he was in israel so it would seem that one should alert people if one is changing one's location from his ususal location so people dont think one is being mechalel shabbat.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: The ops question was halakhic. Nothing in this post addresses halakha.